# Firefox 50 freezes

Tags: windows-7, firefox, freeze

Yesterday I installed FF 50 over my existing FF 49.0.2 on Win7. Prior to the update, I never had any issues with FF. Now, FF 50 freezes, that is:

- I can launch it
- It will show as two tabs in the task bar
- It will let me type a URL but will not respond to Enter, i.e. not load the page
- It will not let me open the settings screen
- It will not close when clicking on the X in the upper right corner

The only add-on I've installed is uBlock origin.

I deleted the profile folder. After that, FF asked me whether to import stuff from IE (which I take is the normal behaviour). It will let me open the settings screen and respond normally. However, after closing FF and restarting it, the same behaviour as described above can be observed.

Repeating the exercise (deleting the profile folder) has the same effect again.

Btw, FF 50 from portableapps.com works like a charm (workaround for now).

Any ideas would be much valued.

---Update 2016-11-26---

@DaaBoss - Thanks for your suggestions. I installed FF 50 from scratch but to no avail. Same behaviour as when upgrading from FF 49 via the auto update.

@aurelien - My problem occurs on my Windows machine. The linux box works flawlessly :).

@Placebo12 - I agree with DavidPostill. I don't see how defragging the drive could help in solving the problem in the slightest.

Anyway, I still haven't found the solution. I am 99.99% sure that the problem is not caused by malware. Another weird thing is that when I tried to install Vivaldi as an alternative, Vivaldi seems to install correctly but does not start at all.

I reckon it's time to reinstall. The system has been running for 6+ years without the slightest problems.

Comment: Did you install it while it was running?  Typically, this should work, and then will run v50 after restarting FF.  Regardless, since you've already deleted your profile, try uninstalling and reinstalling v50 from scratch. This will ensure no other plugins OR add-ons are running.  Then add uBlock origin. (uBo is great, BTW. How did they design it that brilliantly??).

Comment: I did uninstall FF completely. After rolling back to FF 49, the issues were gone. Upon updating to FF 50, the problems were back again.

Comment: Try installing v50 without updating from v49.  If that doesn't work, try it on another PC.

Comment: Could you load it from the terminal: `strace firefox` That will provide you a full trace of the software stack.

Comment: You should probably report [a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) instead.

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest uninstalling Firefox, and then restart and defrag your laptop.

If you don't have a defrag app, this one is free and works very well and quickly.

http://ultradefrag.sourceforge.net/en/?download

After defrag, you can download the latest version of Firefox again here.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?gclid=Cj0KEQiAvNrBBRDe3IOwzLn6_O4BEiQAmbK-DkMUCIRT91L7EUPsfdvNpgPSdgSATNN66tH5lZs3OVwaAkZi8P8HAQ&utm_campaign=Firefox-Brand-US-GGL-Exact&utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_source=google&utm_term=mozilla%20firefox

Comment: Please explain why a fragmented hard disk could cause the OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a program that can see the process threads of Firefox, I'm using "Process Hacker" for this. Now there should be 2 Firefox process that can be seen, see both process threads, try finding a thread called ucrtbase.DLL!crt_at_quick_exit that has the priority of -3, change it to normal and that might fix it and any other that show strange number. Also if you like you can have the same preference as me to somewhat stabilize Firefox by changing this threads to certain priority:

WINMM.dll!timeGetTime to highest

if there's any thread at time critical priority change it to highest too

might need to check from time to time, but change are permanent it seem